# r: function to extract and fill in missing dates on rows with multiple follow-up dates

Tags: r, function, dataframe, date, dplyr

I am looking for a function to repeat the following exercise. I have a large dataset `p` in which each row correspond to a patient.
Each patient has dates corresponding to multiple MRI scans and dates corresponding to multiple clinical follow-ups. Each patient may have up to 20 follow-ups of each follow-up type.

The following column names are autogenerated in REDCap, and I admit they are unnecessarily long.

**MRI Dates**

`p$mr_daterd` correspond to the first MRI scan used at diagnosis, and

each subsequent MRI scan is denoted as `p$mr_daterd_fu1_v1` (first MRI follow-up), `p$mr_daterd_fu1_v2` (second MRI follow-up), `p$mr_daterd_v2_v3` (third MRI follow-up) `...` `p$mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17_v18_v19_v20` (the 20th MRI follow-up)

**Clinical follow-up**

`p$date_contact_1` correspond to the first clinical follow-up, and

each subsequent clinical follow-up is denoted as `p$contact_date_2` (second clinical follow-up), `p$contact_date_3` (third clinical follow-up) `...` `p$contact_date_20`(the 20th clinical follow-up).

Hence the suffix `_vX` and `_x` matches sequentially between each MRI and clinical follow-up.

I need to replace NA / missing dates in *the clinical follow-up*, exclusively. I.e. if `p$date_contact_x` is NA / missing, it should be replaced with the corresponding `xth` MRI follow-up date.

Ala `p$date_contact_x = ifelse(is.na(p$date_contact_x), p$mr_daterd_vx, p$date_contact_x)`.
However, I would prefer not to define each follow-up date as such, and rather include a function to do this repeatedly for each follow-up.

I am using `dplyr`, so a solution compatible with this package is preferable.

**Example**

```
  id date_contact_3 date_contact_7 mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3 mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7
1 10           <NA>           <NA>                <NA>                      2009-03-16
2 14           <NA>           <NA>          2012-03-09                            <NA>
```

**Expected output**

```
  id date_contact_3 date_contact_7 mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3 mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7
1 10           <NA>     2009-03-16                <NA>                      2009-03-16
2 14     2012-03-09           <NA>          2012-03-09                            <NA>
```

**Data sample including all 20 MRI and clinical follow-ups for nine patients**

```
p <- structure(list(id = 32:40, mr_daterd = structure(c(15271, 12958, 
15236, 12467, 12958, 15125, 12958, 11541, 13696), class = "Date"), 
    mr_daterd_fu1_v1 = structure(c(15716, 15785, 15391, 16307, 
    15764, 15474, 15932, 11765, 13976), class = "Date"), mr_daterd_fu1_v2 = structure(c(16086, 
    16504, 15758, NA, 16602, 15836, 16652, 12169, 14389), class = "Date"), 
    mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3 = structure(c(16451, NA, 16097, NA, NA, 
    16209, NA, 12538, 14821), class = "Date"), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4 = structure(c(17323, 
    NA, 16511, NA, NA, 16564, NA, 12888, 15146), class = "Date"), 
    mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5 = structure(c(18130, NA, 17974, 
    NA, NA, 17365, NA, 13241, 15496), class = "Date"), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6 = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 13732, 16232), class = "Date"), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7 = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 17308), class = "Date"), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8 = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15243, NA), class = "Date"), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9 = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15693, NA), class = "Date"), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10 = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 16421, NA), class = "Date"), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17_v18 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17_v18_v19 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17_v18_v19_v20 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), date_contact_1 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), date_contact_2 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), date_contact_3 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), date_contact_4 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), date_contact_5 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), date_contact_6 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), date_contact_7 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), date_contact_8 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), date_contact_9 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), date_contact_10 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), date_contact_11 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), date_contact_12 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), date_contact_13 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), date_contact_14 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), date_contact_15 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), date_contact_16 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), date_contact_17 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), date_contact_18 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), date_contact_19 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), date_contact_20 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` approach

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

p %>% 
  mutate(across(
    starts_with("date_contact"), 
    ~{
      vn <- paste0("v", str_match(cur_column(), "(?<=_)\\d+$"))
      x <- cur_data_all() %>% select(starts_with("mr_daterd") & ends_with(vn)) %>% pull()
      coalesce(., x)
    }
  ))
```

Output

```
  id  mr_daterd mr_daterd_fu1_v1 mr_daterd_fu1_v2 mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3 mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4 mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5 mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6 mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7 mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8 mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9 mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10 mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11 mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12 mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13 mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14 mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15 mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16 mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17 mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17_v18 mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17_v18_v19 mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17_v18_v19_v20 date_contact_1 date_contact_2 date_contact_3 date_contact_4 date_contact_5 date_contact_6 date_contact_7 date_contact_8 date_contact_9 date_contact_10 date_contact_11 date_contact_12 date_contact_13 date_contact_14 date_contact_15 date_contact_16 date_contact_17 date_contact_18 date_contact_19 date_contact_20
1 32 2011-10-24       2013-01-11       2014-01-16          2015-01-16             2017-06-06                2019-08-22                         <NA>                            <NA>                               <NA>                                  <NA>                                      <NA>                                          <NA>                                              <NA>                                                  <NA>                                                      <NA>                                                          <NA>                                                              <NA>                                                                  <NA>                                                                      <NA>                                                                          <NA>                                                                              <NA>     2013-01-11     2014-01-16     2015-01-16     2017-06-06     2019-08-22           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>
2 33 2005-06-24       2013-03-21       2015-03-10                <NA>                   <NA>                      <NA>                         <NA>                            <NA>                               <NA>                                  <NA>                                      <NA>                                          <NA>                                              <NA>                                                  <NA>                                                      <NA>                                                          <NA>                                                              <NA>                                                                  <NA>                                                                      <NA>                                                                          <NA>                                                                              <NA>     2013-03-21     2015-03-10           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>
3 34 2011-09-19       2012-02-21       2013-02-22          2014-01-27             2015-03-17                2019-03-19                         <NA>                            <NA>                               <NA>                                  <NA>                                      <NA>                                          <NA>                                              <NA>                                                  <NA>                                                      <NA>                                                          <NA>                                                              <NA>                                                                  <NA>                                                                      <NA>                                                                          <NA>                                                                              <NA>     2012-02-21     2013-02-22     2014-01-27     2015-03-17     2019-03-19           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>
4 35 2004-02-19       2014-08-25             <NA>                <NA>                   <NA>                      <NA>                         <NA>                            <NA>                               <NA>                                  <NA>                                      <NA>                                          <NA>                                              <NA>                                                  <NA>                                                      <NA>                                                          <NA>                                                              <NA>                                                                  <NA>                                                                      <NA>                                                                          <NA>                                                                              <NA>     2014-08-25           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>
5 36 2005-06-24       2013-02-28       2015-06-16                <NA>                   <NA>                      <NA>                         <NA>                            <NA>                               <NA>                                  <NA>                                      <NA>                                          <NA>                                              <NA>                                                  <NA>                                                      <NA>                                                          <NA>                                                              <NA>                                                                  <NA>                                                                      <NA>                                                                          <NA>                                                                              <NA>     2013-02-28     2015-06-16           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>
6 37 2011-05-31       2012-05-14       2013-05-11          2014-05-19             2015-05-09                2017-07-18                         <NA>                            <NA>                               <NA>                                  <NA>                                      <NA>                                          <NA>                                              <NA>                                                  <NA>                                                      <NA>                                                          <NA>                                                              <NA>                                                                  <NA>                                                                      <NA>                                                                          <NA>                                                                              <NA>     2012-05-14     2013-05-11     2014-05-19     2015-05-09     2017-07-18           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>
7 38 2005-06-24       2013-08-15       2015-08-05                <NA>                   <NA>                      <NA>                         <NA>                            <NA>                               <NA>                                  <NA>                                      <NA>                                          <NA>                                              <NA>                                                  <NA>                                                      <NA>                                                          <NA>                                                              <NA>                                                                  <NA>                                                                      <NA>                                                                          <NA>                                                                              <NA>     2013-08-15     2015-08-05           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>
8 39 2001-08-07       2002-03-19       2003-04-27          2004-04-30             2005-04-15                2006-04-03                   2007-08-07                            <NA>                         2011-09-26                            2012-12-19                                2014-12-17                                          <NA>                                              <NA>                                                  <NA>                                                      <NA>                                                          <NA>                                                              <NA>                                                                  <NA>                                                                      <NA>                                                                          <NA>                                                                              <NA>     2002-03-19     2003-04-27     2004-04-30     2005-04-15     2006-04-03     2007-08-07           <NA>     2011-09-26     2012-12-19      2014-12-17            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>
9 40 2007-07-02       2008-04-07       2009-05-25          2010-07-31             2011-06-21                2012-06-05                   2014-06-11                      2017-05-22                               <NA>                                  <NA>                                      <NA>                                          <NA>                                              <NA>                                                  <NA>                                                      <NA>                                                          <NA>                                                              <NA>                                                                  <NA>                                                                      <NA>                                                                          <NA>                                                                              <NA>     2008-04-07     2009-05-25     2010-07-31     2011-06-21     2012-06-05     2014-06-11     2017-05-22           <NA>           <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>
```